# Replacing new line with <br> tag express javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a blog website.I am taking the input using a text area and storing it in the mongodb.Before storing the  data in mongodb I perform the following function:

```
      req.body.content=req.body.content.replace(/\n/g ,"<br>");
```

I saw this on another stackoverflow post.
Now the problem is for the first time \n is replaced with 
. Now if I edit the post then the above function is executed again so the 
 tag is added again to the unmodified text(which I don't want to happen).
Ex:
First time:
hello
javascript
world
is replaced as
hello
javascript
world.

Second time(when I edit it):
hello
javascript
express
world
is replaced as

hello
javascript
express
world.

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.replace(/\n(?!\n)/g,"<br>");`

This will ensure that only a `\n` that is not followed by another `\n` will be replaced. (it is called regEx lookahead)

Comment: .replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, ""); or .replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, "");

Comment: @ISAE thank you for replying but it does not work.

Comment: @toto Thank you for replying but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify user input.  Instead, use CSS to format text, e.g.

```css
p { white-space: pre }
```

Comment: Hey.Thank you for replying!It works but  I have 1 small doubt if I had get two line gaps for one line gap that the user gave what can I do?I mean how to replace \n with <br><br>